# C# code generated by Visual Studio 2015 uses .NET types instead of C# keywords

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

For example, the following snapshot depicts generation of a new local variable:

[image]
[image]

What I want is to have it generated as `bool help`, instead of `Boolean help`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @mark, I did a simple test and you can go to Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>Code Style, and check the option "Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword when declaring locals, parameters and members" to make it works as you expected, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgyAboSZOHH2Hg43n

Comment: @Sara-MSFT - thanks. Please, arrange as an answer so I could credit you.

Comment: @Rob: The duplicate explains how to toggle this.

Comment: @SLaks Ah yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, technically no difference between bool and Boolean in c#, because **bool** is the alias for **Boolean** class. 
But you can change code generation setting through tools/options in VS.
[image: As you seen]

You will see that second check box is unchecked in your view. so, make it checked to get auto generated code with alias , instead of class name.

Answer (score 3):

There are settings to control whether type names or keywords are used in generated code.  Look under Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Code Style.